# changing figure height and width in RMarkdown without changing font size or causing blurry image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm wondering, for a ggplot rendered in an RMarkdown HTML output, two things:

1. how does one change the size of the plot without changing the font sizes within the plot?  Is this even possible?  When I adjust `fig.height` and `fig.width` to a larger size, typically, the font is shrunk.
2. The plot looks crisp in the actual RMarkdown document, but adjusting to a larger size seems to make the plot blurry when rendered to HTML:

[image]

Is there a better way to preserve the fidelity of the plot? Should I be doing something other then adjusting fig.height and width?

Comment: I've always used `fig.height` (etc) without seeing a font change. Is this reproducible on other systems?

Comment: Yes, but that causes the plot to be blurry and changes font size.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying, now understand me: I've always used `fig.height` and not seen a font change. It might be something I'm doing that you're not, but there is nothing reproducible in your question, nor have you tested to see if it's either specific to your computer, your OS, or something else.

Comment: I have deal with a similar problem a few times. I always "solve it" playing specifying the text size of each component of the plot.